# Is there a way to show the content right-to-left without manually changing CSS styles?

Tags: views, 8

In a site where some of the pages are written using the Hebrew alphabet, I created a view that displays linked headings of nodes. The title is shown on the right, but the linked headings are on the left.

Is there a way to show a view right-to-left without manually changing CSS styles?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An alternative way so you don't have to change css all the time.

You can probably setup a generic RTL css rule in your theme (one time)

```
.rtl {
    direction: rtl;
}
```

and use this rule in each of your views under `advanced > css class` as you see fit.

**Alternatively** as Leymannx points out you can add `global text area` in the `header` of your view and add the following css

```
<style>.view {direction: rtl;}</style>
```

using `Full HTML` format as shown in the screenshots below

[image]
[image]

**NOTE:** `view` class is included in all views so this solution could potential affect all views on the page